# Android Bucle For TextView no actualiza texto

Tags: android, bucle-for, textview, text

Hola tengo un problema en Android tengo un bucle for que actualiza un TextView del 0 al 10000 pero solo aparece el último valor del for que es 10000 cuando le doy el boton para que Set Text. Lo que quiero hacer es que por cada elemento del for se actualize el TextView en 1 segundo es decir:
Aparece 0 en el TextView pasa 1 segundo... cambia Aparece 1 en el TextView pasa 1 segundo... cambia aparece 2 en el TextView pasa 1 segundo ... cambia aparece n en el TextView pasa 1 segundo... así hasta llegar al 10000

Pero no sucede así aparece el último elemento del for y lo mas curioso es que aparece el ultimo elemento (10000) en el TextView cuando en el logcat todavia esta pintando antes de llegar al último elemento que es el 10000. Les dejo acá el gif.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he probado con **Thread.sleep(10000)** antes del

```
Log.i("for", "" + i)
binding.numero.text = ""+i
```

pero lo que pasa es que no pinta nada en el TextView hasta que llegue al último elemento del for.

Les dejo el código del **MainActivity** aqui:

```
package com.luismiguel.textviewfor

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.luismiguel.textviewfor.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        binding.btnSetText.setOnClickListener{
            pintarForTextView()
        }
        binding.btnVolverAlInicio.setOnClickListener{
            binding.numero.text = ""
            binding.numero.hint = "Numero 0...10000"
        }
    }

    private fun pintarForTextView(){
        for(i in 0 .. 10000){
            Log.i("for", "" + i)
            binding.numero.text = ""+i
        }
    }
}
```

Les dejo el código fuente aquí: https://github.com/Miguel546/fortextview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que cuando usas `Thread.sleep()` el thread se bloquea por completo y entonces no se puede actualizar la ui. La mejor solución es crear una corrutina y usar la función `delay` para hacer la pausa sin bloquear el thread.

```
private fun pintarForTextView() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        for (i in 0..10000) {
            Log.i("for", i.toString())
            binding.numero.text = i.toString()
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
}
```

En este [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-introduction-coroutines) se explican los problemas que ocurren cuando usas threads y como puedes usar las corrutinas de kotlin para solucionarlos.

Comment: Me salio este error android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. Con el codigo.         
 private fun pintarForTextView(){
        GlobalScope.launch {
            for (i in 0..10000) {
                Log.i("for", i.toString())
                binding.numero.text = i.toString()
                delay(1000)
            }
        }
        
    }

Comment: eso es porque usaste `GlobalScope`. El scope `lifecycleScope` viene en la librería [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle) de jetpack. Si no lo tienes usa `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)`

Comment: Sabes porque no funciona cuando pongo el lifecycleScope dentro del for asi de esta manera: for (i in 0..10000) {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                Log.i("for", i.toString())
                binding.numero.text = i.toString()
                delay(1)
            }
        } y porque si funciona cuando lo pongo afuera del for?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es lo la velocidad en la que se ejecuta cada linea,
cada loop al menos debe durar medio segundo.
Ponle un hilo en cada loop.

mHandler.postDelayed(monitor, 1000); // 1 second

Comment: Christian con mHandler.postDelayed(monitor, 1000) se tiene que esperar el delay que pones y luego comienza a llenar el for pero sin ninguna pausa lo hace de manera inmediata.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso estas tratando de modificar la UI por lo tanto deberìas usar runOnUiThread :

```
runOnUiThread(
        object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                 // Cambia elementos de la UI aquì...
            }
        }
)
```

realizalo de esta forma en tu mètodo `pintarForTextView()`:

```
 private fun pintarForTextView(){
        for(i in 0 .. 10000){
            Log.i("for", "" + i)

            runOnUiThread(
                 object : Runnable {
                    override fun run() {
                      // Cambia elementos de la UI aquì...
                      binding.numero.text = ""+i
                    }
                 }
              )
                
        }
    }
```

Comment: No funciona con tu respuesta pinta 10000 primero y en la consola ni termina de llegar al 10000